# Exception occurred processing WSGI script Flask Apche2 EC2

Tags: python, flask, apache2.4

my wsgi file

```
#dico.wsgi
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/disco')

from disco import app as application

application.debug = True
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 10.402.120.106

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        WSGIDaemonProcess disco threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/disco/disco.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/html/disco>
                WSGIProcessGroup disco
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

error.logs

```
mod_wsgi (pid=505): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/disco/disco.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=505): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/disco/disco.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/disco/disco.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
from disco import app as application
File "/var/www/html/disco/disco/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from flask import Flask, abort, request, jsonify, g, url_for, make_response, Response, redirect
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

My python scripts executing fine locally, but when I put it in server with wsgi config and apache2 config getting like above errors.
mod_wsgi (pid=505): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/disco/disco.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=505): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/disco/disco.wsgi'

Please help me, I badly stuck with this but running fine in my local system.

Comment: make pip list and check if flask installed in python-package and check system on which python version or path of python-packages working

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your virtual environment path and run activate file on wsgi file. And if there are, don't forget environmental variables.

```
python_home = '/usr/local/envs/myapp1'

activate_this = python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```